# When loading css from a javascript file, how should I keep the html output hidden until the css file is loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, plugins, load, hide

When javascript creates the parent div that all of my output is contained in, I am hiding it with `element.style.display = 'none'`. For performance purposes, I think having my plugin (javascript) load the css file at the beginning is the fastest way. Then the css will make the parent div visible again once it loads. However, if the css file loads before the div is created, wouldn't javascript still hide it when it gets to that point in the code? Using an !important tag here would seem cheap. Alternatively, loading the css file after creating the div would just mean the output would take longer to be displayed to the user. I'm wondering if there is a standard solution to this, but haven't been able to find one. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "Using an !important tag here would seem cheap"

Comment: How long are you expecting it to take to download the CSS? It seems a little over-engineered to me.

Comment: I agree. This seems like premature optimization.

Comment: @flem I can see what you mean. It shouldn't take long in this case, but I think it would still be good to have a solution. I'd rather the user see a spinner until everything is done AND the css is applied, just in case the css takes a while.

Parv, In my mind, using the important tag to prevent javascript from doing what it is trying to do seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
   body { display: none; }
</style>
<script>
   window.onload = function(){ document.body.style.display = null; }
</script>
```

You might check whether the CSS link ref is loaded, that's higher level, but I recommend the JavaScript book by David Flanagan.

Better way is to use pure CSS - it happens automatically and doesn't wait for document load.

```
<style>
   body { display: none; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css">
```

In `some.css` file:

```
body { display: inherit; }
```

Not sure about `inherit`, maybe `block` will work. Try.

Comment: I always use `block` and have never had any problems with it. Perhaps `inherit` won't work because body has no parents? It is the top level element.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the wrapper DIV, give is a class name of something like "hideMe", and have a definition of hideMe as `display:none`. When you want to show it, remove the class (or redefine it).

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery and solve this with:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $(element).show();
});
```

or

```
$(window).load( function() {
   $(element).show();
});
```